# A question on "law of congruence of modulus"

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules

I have a quick question about the law of congruence of modulus, which states

"Let $a•b≡a•c \,(\mod m)$, where $a$ is not equivalent to $0$,$ \mod m$.

We can cancel $a$ only when $a$ and $m$ are relatively *prime*.

If $a$ is relatively prime to $m$, then
$b≡c (\mod m)$"

**Source:** http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/numberTheory/modularArithmetic.htm#mozTocId18123

The proof is easy enough to understand and the theorem also seems simple, but I keep *finding* examples that go against it, which means I am not fully understanding the theorem. I need someone to point out the flaw in my thinking, please, and explain it to me like I'm $5$ (preferably)

**An example that does work:** 
$9 ≡ 21 (\mod 4)$ means we can cancel $3$ and get $3 ≡ 7 (\mod 4)$ (because $3$ and $4$ are prime), which is true (because $ 3 \mod 3$ is $3$, and $7 \mod 4$ is also $3$)

**An example that does not work:**
$9 ≡ 18 (\mod 4)$ means we can cancel $3$ and get $3 ≡ 6 \mod 4$ (because 3 and 4 are prime), but that's not true because $3 \mod 4$ is $3$, and $6 \mod 4$ is 2.

Thanks in advance!

Edited 5/16
Alright I understand now (and feel silly about it). It didn't make sense at the end because the beginning didn't make any sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Error:** $9\not \equiv 18 \pmod{4}$

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is wrong:

$$ 18 \mod{4}=2 \not= 1= 9 \mod{}4$$